# Add custom fields in Windows Phone/8 app manifest file

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to add custom fields in app manifest for windows phone (WMAppManifest.xml) and windows 8 (package.appxmanifest) apps?

Along with existing properties in app manifest, I want developers to set additional properties in app manifest which can later read by application code. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Why bother piggybacking on the manifest?  Just use project settings or resoruces for this purpose.

Comment: As part of SDK that I am writing, I am reading bunch of fields such as App Name, Description from manifest. Optionally, I can include extra XML when SDK is installed and have developer update that but It would be nice if I am able to ask developer to go at one place and update this information.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** The manifest file is a strictly defined element that is used to to describe the app and its capabilities. No additional fields or metadata is allowed outside the boundaries of the existing attributes and nodes.

You should use a different way to add application metadata, such as the isolated storage or the project itself.

Comment: Is there any way to read the manifest file from within code?  I have not been able to find a good way to do this.